# Why is "Add to Wishlist" option not visible in iOS 7 App Store?

Tags: ios-appstore, ios

I've found several apps that I'd like to add to my wishlist to download later, but the option isn't visible in the menu. I thought "Add to Wishlist" was a new feature in iOS 7 for the App Store. But the only options I see are Airdrop, Message, Mail, Twitter, Facebook, and Copy Link. Is anyone else having this issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I do believe that you are attempting to add Free apps to your wishlist.  When you try this you do not get the open to add to your wishlist, just as you never could gift a free app.  Try again on a paid app and you should see the options *Add to Wish List* and *Gift* appear before *Copy Link*.

Comment: Oh man, you're right. What's the deal with that?? Hopefully they'll add that option to free apps in the future.

Comment: The wishlist is really there to allow other people to gift you those apps that you add to it.  Anything that is free you might as well just download immediately if you want it, especially if it can't be gifted anyway.  Whilst using it as a novel app bookmarking feature seems possible, it's not the intended usage.

Comment: Yeah, I was just hoping to be able to "bookmark" an app to download when I'm at home and on WiFi.

Comment: @hw731 If you have `Use Cellular Data` turned off in `Settings > iTunes & App Stores`, then downloading an app *will* effectively bookmark it until you're on WiFi. :)

Comment: @DanJ - I turned off `Use Cellular Data` and tried downloading an app and it went ahead and downloaded. Am I missing something?

Comment: @hw731 Hmm. I may have incorrectly assumed explicit downloads on cellular would be blocked by that setting; it might just be *automatic* downloads that are prevented. Could be just the size limit that blocks (some) app downloads on cellular. Apologies.

Comment: If the goal is for gifting, then how do I discover my friend's wishlist to buy a gift for them? Or how do I share my wishlist with others? There appears to be no share button within the wishlist view.

Answer (score -3):

I believe it will wait for a wifi connection if the download is over 100mb.